# What's CMAKE usage of "set" without value?

Tags: cmake

I was reading cmakelists of a big project when i found this

`set(${FOLDER_NAME}_HR  PARENT_SCOPE)`

and what i understand that set must have a value, so what does it mean? is this var will be defined with empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#command:set):

Zero arguments mean the variable will be unset. `PARENT_SCOPE` means it will be unset for the scope above the current one i.e. in a script that calls this script the variable is set and in the one you found it - it unsets it for it.

Comment: ok, this means that this equals command "UNSET", right?

Comment: @mr.Arrow More precisely it's equivalent to `unset(${FOLDER_NAME}_HR  PARENT_SCOPE)`

Comment: As @fabian stated